# About mysql auto increment behavior when inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

I will be working with mysql for a project. I have some tables with primary key as an integer that auto increments (call it id).

When I insert something that cannot be inserted (for example, a unique field ip, and you insert the same ip) it does not let you insert (which is ok!) but then, id is incremented... Which is not correct because I tried to insert, but I cant.

```
Is this a normal behavior?
```

how I can assure that the id will be only incremented when "okay" values are inserted?

Thank you

Comment: auto incremented ID's are meant to be behind the scenes...it shouldn't matter if they read 21047132123 or 1.  It is normal behavior in Mysql.  Not to be crass or anything, but why do you care when it's incremented?

Comment: I was just curious if it is a normal behavior... But it looks then that I can do an exploit (in some way) if I can insert many times to have overflow right?

Comment: It is, Bill Karwin's answer explains well.  Remember auto incremented ID's are never intended to be row numbers, they are simply intended to be unique.  If you were looking to assign an ID for display that needs to be sequential, then I'd set up an auto incremented ID column and let it do what it does best (keep rows unique and join tables on) and a second column called 'display_ID' or something to that extent and populate it yourself.

Comment: @Twelfth, note that populating that consecutive display id would require table-locking to avoid race conditions, so you'd be back to a small-scale solution either way.

Comment: @BillKarwin If he was assigning it at the time of insertion, yes.  A nightly (or hourly) script that went through and assigned sequential ID's would work.  'populate it yourself' can be done at several points...but you are right if you are trying to real-time assign sequential ID's.  Personally I think the need for 'sequential ID's' in a database is to misunderstand a few database fundamentals...data is inherently not sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. Since MySQL 5.1, InnoDB releases the auto-inc lock for a table as soon as possible to allow concurrent threads to do their own inserts without waiting for your thread. This means the auto-inc lock is released before the INSERT is known to succeed. So if anything goes wrong with the INSERT, it can't "return" the auto-incremented value, because another thread may have already allocated the N+1st auto-inc value, and InnoDB doesn't track anything except the most recent auto-inc value.

This does result in some cases where a lot of auto-inc values are "lost" if you have many failed inserts. For example, I helped one site that ran all the way up to the maximum signed INT value (2<sup>31</sup>-1) because they were skipping 1000-1500 values for every row that was successfully inserted. All because of a secondary UNIQUE constraint on their username column.

You can make InnoDB behave like it did in MySQL 5.0, to let auto-increment values return their incrementation on a failed INSERT by setting `innodb_auto_inc_lock_mode=0` in the my.cnf config file.
Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html for more details.

Be aware, though, that this limits concurrency, because a thread inserting will hold the auto-inc for a longer time. Other threads have to wait for the currently inserting thread to completely succeed before they can acquire the auto-inc lock. If you have a high rate of concurrent inserts against the same table, this can slow down your app.

Also, it's normal for there to be gaps in the primary key sequence, because some transactions are rolled back anyway, or else rows get deleted. Never assume your primary key values are going to be perfectly consecutive. They are intended to be unique values, not row numbers.

Comment: thanks! by the way, did you fix the problem company in that way?

Comment: I told them of the option, but they preferred not to sacrifice scalability. The option would change the locking behavior for *all* tables, not just the one they had the issue with. They ended up choosing to SELECT the table for a conflicting username before attempting the INSERT. That's a race condition, because another session could sneak in and insert a conflicting username in between the SELECT and the INSERT. But it reduced the number of lost id's a great deal.